# Gnuplot fat lines overlap with axis

Tags: gnuplot

Heyho!

I need to make some lines with gnuplot. However due to the small size of the plots, I want to make those lines fat. However they overlap now with the axis. and into the normal picture. How can I cut those lines of so they dont do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are plotting data, you can adjust the overall x and y ranges so that the lines don't overlap with the borders:

```
set xrange [xmin:xmax]
set yrange [ymin:ymax]
```

If you are plotting functions, you can also cut off lines by adjusting the range when you plot:

```
plot [xmin:xmax][ymin:ymax] ...
```

This is a little more tricky because the function will automatically go to the edge of the plot anyway.  If this is the case, you can specify a larger range for a blank line:

```
plot [-2:2][-2:2] NaN notitle, [-1:1] x**2 title 'x^2'
```